# Confirm on href link before deleting

Tags: javascript, php, html

I plan to have a confirmation box before the script deletes from the database, just in case of the wrong line been selected.

Code for the href

```
echo '<td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="delete.php?id='.$row["id"].'" class="confirmation"><img src="img/icon/delete.png"></a></td>';
```

Java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('confirmation');
    var confirmIt = function (e) {
        if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) e.preventDefault();
    };
    for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
        elems[i].addEventListener('click', confirmIt, false);
    }
</script>
```

When the 'delete' image is pressed it just deletes the row, no confirmation box appears?

Comment: Hey Joseph, are you sure the elems array is not empty so the loop is actually going through your confirmation links?

Comment: make sure that the script tag is at the end of your page, or at least after the links.

Comment: worked a treat @YazanWYusuf thank you.

Comment: I feel that @YazanWYusuf should be posting an answer for this, even though there were some posted "after", it's only fair.

Comment: @JosephThomasMallinson I've posted an answer on your comment. I hope you'll accept it if my answer really helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the script tag is at the end of your page, or at least after the links.

Comment: Adding that jQuery could also be used. Then the script can be defined at the top. The logic would then be started in the onPageLoaded eventhandler.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

```
echo '<td align="center" valign="middle"><a data-href="delete.php?id='.$row["id"].'" href="javascript:;" onclick="confirmToDelete(this);"><img src="img/icon/delete.png"></a></td>';
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
  function confirmToDelete(element){
    if(!element) return false;
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')) self.location.href=element.getAttribute('data-href');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That works, but it involves mixing document structure with application logic - not a good idea in the long term.

Comment: That works, but it involves mixing document structure with application logic - not a good idea in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

try following code. You can do it without external javascript. just add `confirm` function in `onlick` event of your link.

PHP

```
echo '<td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="delete.php?id='.$row["id"].'" class="confirmation" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\');"><img src="img/icon/delete.png"></a></td>';
```